# Indentation after chain of method calls

Tags: eclipse, indentation

Even though I should have the same setup as the rest of my team, Eclipse's formatter has one small anomaly in my setup.

You can see the difference in the attached picture.
On the left is my formatting.
On the right is the rest of the team's formatting.
I want to have the same formatting as the rest of the team.

[image]
The difference arises when there is an empty line after a chain of method calls.

**Question: How do I achieve the formatting on the right?**

Answer (score 0):

I expect you are using the same formatter definition and have already tried to export the formatter on one of your team members machine and import it on yours.

Another thing you should check are the Save Actions in the preferences (`Java` -> `Editor` -> `Save Actions`). Maybe the settings for removing whitespaces differs here.

Comment: Yes, we have a shared formatter, and I recently set it up anew.
I just checked `Save Actions` without success. 
The only relevant setting that I could find is `Code Organizing` -> `Formatter` -> `Remove trailing whitespace`, which is set to `Ignore empty lines`.